# how to display the input in a desired format

Tags: tcl

input file contains some contents such as :

```
15-05-2011  16:05    <DIR>          .
15-05-2011  16:05    <DIR>          ..
24-04-2011  16:07    <DIR>          Administrator
15-05-2011  16:05    <DIR>          confuser
01-02-2011  20:57    <DIR>          Public
29-01-2011  19:28    <DIR>          TechM
12-08-2011  09:36    <DIR>          vt0013487
```

I need to give the file name in the command line argument

the output to be in the desired format:

```
Administrator 24-04-2011  16:07 
confuser      15-05-2011  16:05 
Public        01-02-2011  20:57 
TechM         29-01-2011  19:28 
vt0013487     12-08-2011  09:36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're doing some fixed-width-field input parsing except that the final field is variable length and extends to the end of the line. That's easy enough. The only awkward bit is that we need to read in all the lines to get the width for the first field of the output format.

Assuming you supply the input on stdin (i.e., by redirection) and want it on stdout (so you can also redirect that to a file):

```
##### Read in and compute the width
set len 0
while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
    set date [string range $line 0 16]
    set name [string range $line 36 end]
    lappend lines $name $date
    if {[string length $name] > $len} {
        set len [string length $name]
    }
}
##### Write out as formatted
foreach {name date} $lines {
    puts [format "%-*s %s" $len $name $date]
}
```

Comment: will your method work if we dont know the contents of the file which we are arranging in the sequencial order. for instance we dont know the way with which the contents are present in the file but we need to rearrange the contents in the required manner. User_____ Date ______ Time

Comment: @deva: Alas, no, because the widths could change. Handling a general tabular format is insanely difficult, but it becomes much simpler once it can be constrained even a little. Ask another question, giving as many details of the problem you're trying to _really_ solve as you can.

Comment: kindly explain this script as i am having a hard time understanding the work it does in the script; 

puts [format "%-*s %s" $len $name $date]

The '-' is for left aligning, am i right? if so what is * for? and as you are formating only 'name' and 'date' strings, how am i getting the 'time' string also in the received output?

Answer (score 1):

`split` to break the input into lines, `foreach` to iterate over them, `regexp` to extract relevant groups of characters from those lines, `format` to construct resulting strings (`format` is often not needed in Tcl as simple variable substitution in strings usually works just okay for common cases).

Read [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/split.htm), [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/regexp.htm) and [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/format.htm). Also [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm) for the syntax used by the `regexp` matching engine.

Also I suspect you may be trying to use the output generated by `exec`'ing the DOS `dir` command instead of using `glob` to traverse directories and files natively.  If so, this is wrong, use [`glob`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/glob.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question: If you are calling `cmd /c dir`, here's a way to do it in Tcl:

```
package require struct::list
set files [glob *]
set maxlen [tcl::mathfunc::max {*}[struct::list map $files {apply {s {string length $s}}}]]
foreach file [lsort $files] {
    set datetime [clock format [file mtime $file] -format {%d-%m-%Y %H:%M}]
    puts [format {%-*s %s} $maxlen $file $datetime]
}
```

Comment: good point, you are better off doing it in TCL if you can rather than shelling out the task then having to clean it up afterwards

Comment: @glenn: like you said this may not answer my question but it does give me a different thing to be learnt about. please explain me your script as i have no idea about what these commands are capable of doing.

Comment: First, I'll point you to the documentation: [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/contents.htm) (especialy [this one](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)) and [here](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/). If you're new to Tcl, use the [TclTutor](http://www.msen.com/~clif/TclTutor.html). Please ask about any particular commands you're uncertain about.